# Disabling YouTube's drag down for miniplayer functionality

Tags: javascript, youtube

If I watch a YouTube video and try to drag the player down, it's doing this: [image]

Sometimes it doesn't do this. Sometimes it's only doing this in fullscreen. Sometimes it's also doing this in theatre mode. It started happening not so long ago.

I've tried
`document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => { e.stopImmediatePropagation(); e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();}, true)` 
in Tampermonkey, but it disables all the other mousemoves except the drag down for miniplayer. I've tried `user-select: none`, but it doesn't solve this issue either.

I've tried in Incognito mode, with extensions disabled. Nothing helped.

I'm running latest Chrome. 95.0.4638.54

This doesn't happen in Chromium for some reason: version 94.0.4606.81

I'm not the only one with this problem: https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/l4falt/is_there_a_way_to_turn_off_the_drag_down_to/

I haven't found any other forum posts about it.

Is there any way to disable this functionality?

Update: this code seems to work: https://pastebin.com/n093g9Ur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bit difficult, but to solve this problem:

1. First it was necessary to find the element which listens to user events which trigger this behaviour, by using Ctrl-Shift-C on YouTube player's element and then adding "pointer-events: 'none'" to its parent elements' CSS, until it disables this functionality.
2. The element that was listening for the events can be selected with
   `document.querySelector('ytd-page-manager #player-container');` (it
   turns out there are multiple elements with `player-container` id on
   YouTube).
3. Then we get event listeners for this element by typing "getEventListeners(temp1)" in Chrome developer console (where temp1 is the 'ytd-page-manager #player-container' element after right clicking and choosing "store as a global variable")
4. Then we add our own event listener with Capture:true and stop immediate propagation for these events (it was enough to do for the "pointerdown" event)

So after the page has loaded the code would be

```
const container = document.querySelector('ytd-page-manager #player-container');
console.log(container)
container.addEventListener('pointerdown', (e) => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}, true)
```

We add "true" to the event listener to use Capture ("A boolean value indicating that events of this type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree" -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Please, [remember accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/). Thank you.